# Can I use this sequence to prove Weierstrass Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Be $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous on $[a,b]$. I want to prove that f has a maximum (Weierstrass Theorem) in this way.

> I choose a sequence $x_n \subset [a,b]$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = sup_{x \in [a,b]}f(x) $.
>
> $[a,b]$ is closed and limited, so I can extract a subsequence $y_n$ of $x_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = m \in [a,b]$.
>
> So $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(y_n) = f(m)$. Using that f is continuous and $y_n$ is a subsequence of $x_n$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(y_n) = f(m) = sup_{x \in [a,b]}f(x)$.

So f has a a maximum. My doubt is: can i actually use $x_n$ without any problems in this proof. Why?

Comment: $x_n$ may not be converges. You can extract a convergence subsequence $y_n$ from $x_n$ since $[a,b]$ is compact.

Comment: I thought the same thing. I found this proof on an Analysis book, so i think that $x_n$ actually exists. But how to prove (or disprove) this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The proof is fine & standard. What do you mean by 'can i actually use $x_n$ without any problems in this proof'?

Comment: I try to make myself clear: i don't know why $x_n$ exists.

Comment: If for example, $f$ is constant and $a<b$ then $(x_n)_n$ could be $any$ sequence in $[a,b]$  so we must take a  subsequence to get convergence to some $m$....  A more complicated example is $[a,b]=[0,1],$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=x^2(-1+\sin (1/x))$ for $x\ne 0$.... BTW as a matter of style and thorough rigor, perhaps in the 2nd sentence of your proof you  should say that $(f(y_n))_n$ also converges to $\sup_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)$ because it is a subsequence of the convergent sequence $(f(x_n))_n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of $\sup$, for any $n\in\Bbb N:\ (\sup_{x\in[a,b]} f) - 1/n$ isn't an upper bound, so $\exists x_n\in[a,b]:\ f(x_n) > (\sup_{x\in[a,b]} f) - 1/n$. And as $\sup$ is upper bound:
$$(\sup_{x\in[a,b]} f) - 1/n < f(x_n)\le (\sup_{x\in[a,b]} f).$$

Comment: More precisely, $ \sup f\ge f(x_n)>(\sup f)-1/n$...............+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, edited following your suggestion.